# Preserve the initial order of array in Symfony2 Doctrine findBy()

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entity

I have an array (`$newsList`) of IDs with the following values: `4,2,1,3`.

I'm trying to get some data from the database from entity:

```
$news=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Bundle:News')->findBy(array('id' => $newsList));
```

`$newsList` array represents real IDs from the News entity.

But when I do:

```
foreach($news as $n){
    $n->getId();
}
```

IDs are in order: `1,2,3,4`.

How can I preserve the order from beginning in foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are doing a global query, you can just order your results by a given property, and a given sort order, so as pointed by the previous answer, you can't.

To have your results ordered exactly as the array you given, you can do this:

```
$newsList = [3, 1, 4, 2];
$newsRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Bundle:News');

foreach ($newsList as $id) {
    $new = $newsRepo->findOneBy['id' => $id];

    if ($new !== null) {
        $news[] = $new;
    }
}
```

Like this, your results are ordered exactly like `$newsList`, e.g:

```
foreach ($news as $n) {
    print $n->getId();
}

// Output: 3 1 4 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had a similar conception for this but missed some crucial point, that dit the trick.

Comment: That may be a lot of queries if the `$newsList` is bigger... ;-)

Comment: Sure, it may be better to filter the results after doing the global query, but ATM I don't have a "nice" way in mind. For this small example, it's not a big deal :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

It's how it's returned from DB. If you won't specify `ORDER BY` clause in query, database will return rows *as they are* in storage, and this is usually the same as `id ASC`.

You should sort them on your own in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and the spaceship operator:

```
$newsList = [4, 2, 1, 3];
$news = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(News::class)->findBy(['id' => $newsList]);

$order = array_flip($newsList);
usort($news, function($a, $b) use ($order) {
    return $order[$a->getId()] <=> $order[$b->getId()];
});

// $news is now ordered by id 4,2,1,3
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO the best solution is to use `field` function to get proper news order:

```
$ids = [4, 1, 2, 3];
$news  = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Bundle:News')->createQueryBuilder('n')
    ->select('n, field(n.id, :ids) as HIDDEN field')
    ->where("n.id IN (:ids)")
    ->setParameter('ids', $ids )
    ->orderBy(field)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Note: this solution require custom `field` function that can be found [here](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$news = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Bundle:News')->createQueryBuilder('n')
        ->where("n.id IN(:Ids)")
        ->setParameter('Ids', $newsList ) // $newsList = array(1,2,3,4,...)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: This will generate the same query. Where will be difference here?

Comment: @dragoste I did not know before

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can actually get them sorted from the returning query results, but you can do either of these options:

Do a foreach loop and execute 'findByOne' for each result:

```
foreach($newsList as $id) {
    $news[]=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Bundle:News')->findBy(array('id' => $id));
}
```

Order the results of the query afterwards:

```
$news=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Bundle:News')->findBy(array('id' => $newsList));
foreach($newsList as $id) {
    $sorted_news[] = $news[$id];
}
```